# Issue with returning MemoryStream and memory leak

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-leaks, memorystream

I am having issues with disposing MemoryStream in methods like below. Can you guide on which one to follow and why?

```
public MemoryStream FetchImageStream()
{
    try
    {
        MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream();

        GetObjectResponse getObjectResponse = null; // This is NULL for example only

        using (BufferedStream bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(getObjectResponse.ResponseStream))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[0x3000];
            int count;
            while ((count = bufferedStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                imageStream.Write(buffer, 0, count); // Write the image into memory stream
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        imageStream.Dispose();
    }       

    return imageStream;
}

=============

public void FetchImageStream(out MemoryStream imageStream)
{
    try
    {
        imageStream = new MemoryStream();

        GetObjectResponse getObjectResponse = null; // This is NULL for example only

        using (BufferedStream bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(getObjectResponse.ResponseStream))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[0x3000];
            int count;
            while ((count = bufferedStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                imageStream.Write(buffer, 0, count); // Write the image into memory stream
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        imageStream.Dispose();
    }       

    return imageStream;
}
```

1 : Is there any difference in this two approach. Is one of them or both is prone to memory leak.

2 : In both of them, do we need to explicitly Dispose the memory stream in the method calling them. else it might give memory leak?

Comment: I am returning the MemoryStream from the method..which is the major difference.

Comment: Not at all. As stated in the linked question `MemoryStream`s will be collected by the Garbage Collector, the same as passing a `byte[]`

Answer (score 2):

You'll have more luck if you do something like:

```
using (MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    imageStream = FetchImageStream(imageStream);

    if (imageStream != null)
    {
        // .... do whatever you intended to do with imageStream 
    }

} // this way, it'll be destroyed with it goes out of scope


public MemoryStream FetchImageStream(MemoryStream imageStream )
{
    try
    {
        GetObjectResponse getObjectResponse = null; // This is NULL for example only

        using (BufferedStream bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(getObjectResponse.ResponseStream))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[0x3000];
            int count;
            while ((count = bufferedStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                imageStream.Write(buffer, 0, count); // Write the image into memory stream
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        imageStream.Dispose();

        return null;
    }       

    return imageStream;
}
```

Comment: I would also suggest returning null if there's an exception. Otherwise you're returning a disposed memory stream, and there's no way to differentiate it from a return value that hasn't been disposed. Trying to do anything with a disposed memory stream (other than pointlessly redisposing it) will cause an exception.

Comment: I've updated to reflect